# NVIDIA SLI Not Working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 a few days ago.

I've installed a NVIDIA driver and everything is running really good.
[image: nvidia driver]

Now I wanted to setup SLI. So I've plugged in my second GPU and the SLI bridge:

[image: my graphics cards]

To enable SLI I ran the following command

```bsh
sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=on
```

Now the output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` is:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 440.64

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.64

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ EX3501R"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 155.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 100.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "SLI" "on"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "3440x1440_100 +0+0"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    Option         "SLI" "AFR"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Both GPU's are recognized by the NVIDIA X Server Settings

[image: settings]

but even after rebooting, SLI doesn't seem to be enabled. When I do GPU intensive tasks the `GPU Utilization` of GPU 0 increases, but GPU 1 stays at 0%.

### GPU 0

[image: GPU 0]

### GPU 1

[image: GPU 1]

### Here is my system info

[image: system info]

### SLI bridge

[image: sli bridge]

Answer (score 0):

Try

sudo nvidia-xconfig -sli = on -multigpu = on

Or

sudo nvidia-xconfig -sli = auto -multigpu = auto